# Ways to log data on Suzuki GSXR600-R Engine

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, electronic-control-module

I am working on a university project where we are building a race car with a Suzuki GSXR600-R Engine and ECU. I am wondering if there is any options for how i am able to record data off of this onto a small computer to allow us to view some meaningful data on corner entry speed and rpm.

Does anyone know of any way that data can be read off of these cheaply? As I'm unsure if they support OBD2 which if they did would make everything extremely simple.

Thanks,

Callum

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year is the donor bike?

Comment: If an expert on Suzuki electronics for GSXR600-R isn't able to help, perhaps an open letter to Suzuki with your university project may allow your group entry into the inner circles of factory engineering staff that might be able to help with data gathering. Did you try Suzuki GSXR600-R forums for possible expertise in data acquisition?

Comment: You want the Suzuki SDS diagnostic system. This is usually only available to authorized service centers and is a subscription service. That bike does not appear to support ODB2, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

A microcontroller like an Arduino or ESP32 is needed for the following. The easiest way is to use an RPM sensor at the ignition wire (can be found on Google, see e.g. [here](http://allegrobotics.com/rpm.html). For speed logging, a reed sensor can be used and calculate the impulses per time. The microcontroller can log to an SDCard (adapter needed) or send the data with Bluetooth or wireless LAN to a laptop (ESP32 needed).

Another possibility is to use an OBD Bluetooth adapter with a laptop or microcontroller. I have done this for a BMW G 650 motorcycle, see [here](https://github.com/Ununnilium/650Display/blob/c73a7b455869d92a79c125646770b42c8cad5c42/650Display.ino#L135). For testing, connect the Bluetooth adapter to the diagnostic cable of the ECU (check wiring diagram). Then connect a PC to the Bluetooth adapter, get the virtual COM port in device manager and connect with PuTTY or another serial terminal emulator. Then, try the following commands:

`AT L1`    (for PuTTY, so cursor goes to next line after every answer, not needed on microcontroller)

`AT AL`    (allow long messages)

`AT SP 5`  (sets protocol to KWP2000)

`AT SH 81 12 F1` (set the header, *81* means physical addressing with length, *12* is the [ECU address](https://github.com/aster94/Keyword-Protocol-2000/blob/243d79a08a9dde20b574659909be3a152441e711/src/ISO.h#L103), *F1* is the Bluetooth adapter address, *F3* can also be tried instead

`81`       [starts the communication](https://github.com/aster94/Keyword-Protocol-2000/blob/243d79a08a9dde20b574659909be3a152441e711/src/ISO.h#L49)

`2108`     [request sensor data](https://github.com/aster94/Keyword-Protocol-2000/blob/243d79a08a9dde20b574659909be3a152441e711/src/ISO.h#L76)

You should now receive a byte string. The data positions can be found [here](https://github.com/aster94/Keyword-Protocol-2000/blob/243d79a08a9dde20b574659909be3a152441e711/src/ISO.h#L105).

More information can be found in the ELM327DS, KWP2000 ISO 14230-2 and KWP2000 ISO 14230-3 documents. For the Suzuki implementation [this library](https://github.com/aster94/Keyword-Protocol-2000) is interesting.